# Outline for shapes in Photoshop?

Tags: windows, adobe-photoshop

I'm working on making buttons in PhotoShop. I made a vector round rectangle and gave it a gradient fill. I now want to add an outline around the button. Is there a way to do this with PS?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select the layer then select "fx"

[image]

2. Select "stroke"

[image]